# Insert new/Changes from one table to another in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables with same number of columns :-Table A and Table B
Every day I insert data from Table B to Table A. now the insert query is working

```
insert into table_a (select * from table_b);
```

But by this insert the same data which was inserted earlier that is also getting inserted. I only want those rows which are new or are changed from the old data. How can this be done ?

Comment: take a look at fast-refreshable materialized views. in case your table_a is read-only (no other operation than this insert-select are performed), this could be the easiest option

Answer (score 2):

You can use `minus`:

```
insert into table_a
    select *
    from table_b
    minus
    select *
    from table_a;
```

This assumes that by "duplicate" you mean that all the columns are duplicated.

Comment: In addition, if (by chance) you have a date modified column, select only where the date modified from table b > the max from table a.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a timestamp field, you could use it to limit the records to those created after the last copy.

Another option is, assuming that you have an primary key (`id` column in my example) that you can use to know whether a record has already been copied, you can create a table `c` (with the same structure as `a` and `b`) and do the following:

```
insert into table c 
  select a.* from table a
  left join table b on (a.id=b.id)
  where b.id is null;

insert into table b select * from table c;

truncate table c;
```

You need to adjust this query in order to use the actual primary key.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If the tables have a primary or unique key, then you could leverage that in an anti-join:

```
insert into table_a
select *
from table_b b
where not exists (
  select null
  from table_a a
  where
    a.pk_field_1 = b.pk_field_1 and
    a.pk_field_2 = b.pk_field_2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what your key is. Assuming you have a key ID, that is you only want ID's that are not already in Table A. You can also use Merge-Statement for this:

```
MERGE INTO A USING B ON (A.ID = B.ID)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (... columns of A) VALUES (... columns of B)
```